# Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli

.I have a Problem when I insert Time To the database there's an error..

```
<?php

include ('includes/config.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_UNAME, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME);

if (!$mysqli) {
    throw new Exception($mysqli->connect_error, $mysqli->connect_errno);
}


$tqry = time();
$tqry = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_time(table_time.time) VALUES (?) ");

if (!$tqry) {
    throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
}

$tqry->bind_param('s', $tqry);
$tqry->execute();
?>
```

What Is the error with this?

thanks in advance..

Comment: The argument to `bind_param` should be the time you want to insert, not `$tqry`.

Answer (score 1):

It's here:

```
$tqry->bind_param('s',$tqry);
```

You are binding parameter `s` to `$tqry` which is your MySQL prepared statement. You must store the time in a different variable. See:

```
$tqry = time();
$tqry = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_time(table_time.time) VALUES (?) ");
```

You set `$tqry` to time, then you overwrite it with a prepared statement instead. You should use a different variable name:

```
$now  = time();
$tqry = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_time(table_time.time) VALUES (?) ");
```

Then do:

```
$tqry->bind_param('s', $now);
```